# FastReport.NET RegisterData only one row is printed

Tags: .net, fastreport

I'm using fastreport.net to display a list of items on aspx page.

I pass my data in WebReport1_StartReport() event like this:

WebReport1.Report.RegisterData(myDataView, "myDataSource", 2);
                (WebReport1.Report.FindObject("Data1") as DataBand).DataSource = WebReport1.Report.GetDataSource("myDataSource");

But only one row is printed. However, by using sqlDataSource control and passing data like this: WebReport1.RegisterDataAsp(WebReport1.Report, mySqlDataSource , "mySqlDataSource")

everything is ok.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

DataBand DataSource on report should be assigned

```
((DataBand)report.Report.FindObject("Data1")).DataSource = report.GetDataSource("List");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting this problem for a day or so. I finally discovered that when you create a datasource, the `Enabled` property is set to **false**.

Setting it to **true** makes the rest of the data show up.

```
rpt.RegisterData(data, "MyData", BOConverterFlags.BrowsableOnly, 3);
rpt.GetDataSource("MyData"+).Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the procedures `OnCheckEof`, `OnGetValue`, `OnFirst`, `OnNext`, `OnPrior` events to allow FR to iterate through your dataset.

I only know the Delphi implementation, but I think it can be translated into .NET. You put a `UserDataSet` component in the design view of your form, and open the object inspector/Events tab, and double click on the mentioned events. Then, the IDE will generate the procedures for it and you just need to fill out the missing parts. [Here is an example](http://pastebin.com/ekaxVT6V).

Comment: you may want to provide some sample code to help the user get started solving the issue

Comment: i only know the delphi implementation, but i think it can be translated into .NET
you put a UserDataSet component in the design view of your form, and open the object inspector/Events tab, and double click on the mentioned events and the ide will generate the procedures for it, you just need to fill out the missing parts, for example: [link](http://pastebin.com/ekaxVT6V)

Answer (score 0):

your data section's datasource has been removed;
double click on Data section and set the dataseource to your table;

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as:

```
 WebReport1.Dictionary.Report.RegisterData(myDataView, "myDataSource",true);
```

Then you will get all rows not only first.